# Populating multi select control from multiple values when form opens in AX

Tags: combobox, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009, multivalue

I need to populate multi select dropdown from multiple values from table like this
value1;value2;value corresponding to each record (which is in list box).

When I select any record in list, the value of multiselect combo box changes corresponding to the record in the list box.

I am able to select multiple values for each record manually when I click any record in the list. However, I want the text box of dropdown to be populated automatically whenever I click any record in the list box

Comment: What have you done so far, and what is a "list box"? Do you mean a "grid"?

Comment: Perhaps a screenshot would be useful here.  Also the relation between the 'Record' and the values required?

Answer (score 0):

There is no multiselect combo box control in AX. It can be simulated with a technice based on  `Grid` component and `edit` methods (special method type in X++), but you should clarify your question indeed.